# Python script which generates a CSV for DB rows which haven't updated in a day

Tags: python, sql, csv

I am looking to write a python script which would generate a CSV for DB rows with a unix epoch time which haven't updated in a day or more. My script currently is able to get the results from the queries and generate a csv based off what is stored in the list.

However i'd like it to generate a csv of only those results which haven't updated in a day. My current code:

```
cur = db2.cursor()

#SQL Queries

dbQuery ="SELECT Name FROM Items;"
dbQuery1 ="SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(TheTime, '%W, %D %M %Y') FROM Items;"

results = []
results1 = []

cur.execute(dbQuery)

results.extend(cur.fetchall())

cur.execute(dbQuery1)

results1.extend(cur.fetchall())

with open("Times.csv", "wb") as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter='\t', quotechar=' ')
    csv_writer.writerow(['Name', 'Time'])
    csv_writer.writerows(zip(*[results, results1]))
```

~

Answer (score 2):

Your question doesnt need any database context.

You need to take a row from results and read date column via index or name.
Then take current time with datetime module and count the delta, and see that it is greater than a day, for example in number of seconds (total_seconds()).
Put that in if condition on write only those rows that hit the condition.

You are able to google any part of my explanation pretty easy

Comment: Thank you Maks, I will try what you have suggested!